# how to use fade in and fade up on button click in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to make a simple fade IN and fade out  example in AngularJS.I need show a div with slide up or slide down or fade in fade out as we do in jquery . I have `search`  button on header **(left top button circle)**on click I show search `div` it is working in my plunker. My issue is to do animation...
http://plnkr.co/edit/Z5Y51werBnzM6Yl7tcTB?p=preview
Secondly I need to add `z-index` because it generates new layer. When I click search button **"my name "**  come down when search bar is open. Why?

```
   <ion-view>
    <ion-header-bar align-title="" class="bar-positive">
      <div class="buttons">
      <i style="font-size:25px!important" class="icon-right ion-android-radio-button-off" ng-click="showsearch()"></i>

      </div>
      <h1 class="title">Title!</h1>
      <a class="button icon-right ion-chevron-right button-calm"></a>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <div class="list list-inset searchclass" ng-show="isdiplay">
      <label class="item item-input">
        <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/n2s5u9eifp3y2rz/search_icon.png?dl=0">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search">
      </label>
    </div>
    <ion-contend>
      <div style="margin-top:50px">
      my name
    </div>
    </ion-contend>

    </ion-view>
```

Answer (score 3):

Not trying to attack you here, but just some small feedback:

I took a look at your code and its quite messy to my likings.

your html is not correct ( you have two head tags, two body tags, two html tags?)

also you write

`<ion-contend>` instead of `<ion-content>`

and in your css `z-index=999px` instead of `z-index: 999`

but anyway here you have a plunkr doing exactly what you want it to do:

[Working Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/5IleRfAE2MQ7eT6Tha07?p=preview)

basically what I changed is the following:

To make the search bar fall over the content, you should make its position `absolute` and not `relative`.

Then I used [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) to conditionally apply the fade-in, fade-out css3 animations depending on the state of the search bar (shown/hidden)

css snippet

```
/* Keyframes for the fade-in */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
@-moz-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
@keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }

.fade-in {
  opacity:0;
  -webkit-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;
  -moz-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;
  animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;

  -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
  animation-fill-mode:forwards;

  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
  -moz-animation-duration:0.5s;
  animation-duration:0.5s;
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer can we use slide up and slide down ?

Comment: Yes. I have updated the plunkr. I suggest that you read up a bit on CSS3 animations